# Count number of times a procedure is executed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

**Requirement:**

To count the number of times a procedure has executed

From what I understand so far, `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` can be used for approximate count but that's only since the last service restart. I found this [link on this website](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49670/counting-the-number-of-calls-of-a-stored-procedure) relevant but I need count to be precise and that should not flush off after the service restart.

Can I have some pointers on this, please?

Hack: The procedure I need to keep track of has a select statement so returns some rows that are stored in a permanent table called `Results`. The simplest solution I can think of is to create a column in `Results` table to keep track of the procedure execution, select the maximum value from this column before the insert and add one to it to increment the count. This solution seems quite stupid to me as well but the best I could think of.

Comment: Can you modify the SProc?

Comment: @Richard: Yes, I can.

Comment: Data in dm_exec_procedure_stats disappears even faster, when the plan is dropped from cache.

Comment: Create a sequence and fetch value from it in the procedure?

Comment: @JamesZ: So, what are possible ways to keep accurate permanent track of procedure execution count?

Comment: @JamesZ: Could not follow. Explain a bit, please?

Comment: `SERVER AUDIT` can log executions automatically; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015(v=SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I thought is you could create a sequence object, assuming you're on SQL Server 2012 or newer.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ProcXXXCounter
    AS int
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

And then in the procedure fetch a value from it:

```
declare @CallCount int

select @CallCount = NEXT VALUE FOR ProcXXXCounter
```

There is of course a small overhead with this, but doesn't cause similar blocking issue that could happen with using a table because sequences are handled outside transaction.

Sequence parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: Only avilable in 2012 and later, also if the proc gets rolled back a number would have been increamented and will show you the wrong number of executions.

Comment: @JamesZ : Thank you so much James. That actually looks like what I wanted. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of keeping track of number of executions even when the service has restarted , is to have a table in your database and insert a row to that table inside your procedure everytime it is executed.

Maybe add a datetime column as well to collect more info about the execution. And a column for user who executed etc..

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the kind of hack I mentioned above is somewhat the same but actually looking forward to a more neat way for this :)

Comment: To me its seems pretty neat :) dont think you have many options with your requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, easily and without Enterprise Edition, by using extended events. The sqlserver.module_end event will fire, set your predicates correctly and use a histogram target.

http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/extended-events/predicate-order-matters
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878023(v=sql.110).aspx

To consume the value, query the histogram target (under the reviewing target output examples).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. :) This looks interesting but I am a quite a  newbie with this. Sorry for being a noob but Can I please get  a more basic post to start with? Thanks.